# Unable to login to AC1200MS router config page

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I recently acquired the AC1200MS router from ReadyNet Solutions and have been unable to login to the router's configuration page through my browser.

I am able to access the internet and I'm able to get onto the login page for the router, however, I am unable to login using the credentials provided on the sticker on the bottom of the router. I have read the part of the user manual (linked below) that is supposed to help with logging in and have tried all sorts of user/pass combinations in an attempt to login but nothing has worked.

If any more details are needed please let me know. Any help would be appreciated.

User Manual: http://www.readynetsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/AC1200-User-Manual-v1.4.pdf

P.S. I need to login to my router so that I can do some portforwarding

Comment: In order to fix this problem, you can factory reset your AC1200MS.  Follow the factory reset procedure in the User Manual.  That should set your user/password back to its original state.

Comment: @pythonian after some searching I have not been able to find instructions on resetting my particular router but I have held down the reset button on the back of the router for 30 seconds, which seems to have worked since the name of the network changed to what looks like the default network name, but I still have not been able to login

Comment: Very strange.  I would have thought that a factory reset would have done the trick.  The username is “user” and the password is printed on the
label on the bottom of your router.  Is that how you try to log into the WEB interface?

Comment: If it does not work as stated in the user manual after a factory reset.  I would suggest returning the unit and getting a new one.

Comment: Yes i was using the login info from the back of the router but that wasn't working.  I called my isp today to talk about the issue and it turns out that it is a security feature and to call back for instructions on how to bypass this feature. Thank you for you're help and suggestions, now I'm just left wondering why not allowing users to configure their routers was an included feature.

Comment: @Kanan That's what I was thinking about posting ass an answer, but I read the comments first and you got there before me, so you should post it as an answer to your own question and also click the gray check mark beside your answer to mark it as accepted which changes its color from gray to green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling my ISP, it turns out that this was not a problem but a security feature which I was given the work-around for after asking some questions about it.